# How to give lazy loading in CSSLayout in Vaadin 8?

Tags: layout, vaadin, lazy-loading, vaadin8

Is it possible to apply lazy loading to CSSLayout in Vaadin 8?
As I have more componets in CSSLayout, I want to apply lazy loading to CSSLayout so that page loading time can be reduced.
If lazy loading is not possible then is there any way to give load more button according to different screen sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use LazyLayouts add-on. It is exactly implementing what you are asking for.

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/lazylayouts

Comment: I had already tried it...But it only supports lazy loading for vertical layout...I want to lazy load CSS layout.

Comment: Oh, I assumed that you want to load lazily CSSLayouts to one host layout, what is what this add-on does. Regarding your original target to optimize page load time, it sounded relevant. If you have only one VerticalLayout, which contains many components, optimizing VerticalLayout -> CSSLayout really does not make a difference, but simplifying the components in VerticalLayout really makes difference.